# Subclass of UICollectionViewCell Not Displaying

Tags: cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that is displayed by clicking a table cell within a navigation controller. So the UICollectionView is the second screen in the navigation controller's stack.

Cells showed up fine in the collection view when I registered a nib and created the cell via the UICollectionViewCell class. But once I try to create a subclass for the cell, the collection view just shows up as a black screen. My project can be found here.
[Link to Project in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vltfnskdomkqdty/TxLzWVwJ9i)

To subclass the UICollectionViewCell, I did the following:

- Created the .h and .m files for the subclass of UICollectionViewCell. Referenced this custom class on the nib's attribute inspector.

[image]

- Registered the custom class with the cell's reuse identifier, within viewDidLoad of the view controller that displays the collection view.

  ```
  [self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
  ```
- Created an instance of the custom cell in "collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:"

  ```
  CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  ```

From what I've read, that should do it! But the collection view is showing up blank, can anyone help??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked your code. You have done perfectly. Collection view with cells is showing correctly, but you cannot see that since you are not setting any of the property of the cell. Just check by setting background color of the cell in `cellForItem`

```
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If you are done everything in nib then you need to register nib instead of class. use `registerNib` instead of `registerClass`. If you are registering class you have to do everything programmatically.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very surprised though that the contents of the nib seem to be completely ignored after subclassing UICollectionViewCell. I already had the background set to white (in Interface Builder). I also just put an image in the cell (with an imageView in IB) and it doesn't show up. Do all the contents of a subclassed UICollectionViewCell have to be added programatically? Why does it ignore what's in the nib?

Comment: If you are done everything in nib then you need to register nib instead of class. use __registerNib__ instead of __registerClass__ to register cell. If you are registering class you have to to everything programmatically...:)

Comment: Yep, works just as you described. I registered the nib instead of the class and the nib showed up. Thanks for offering your help here!

Comment: @AnilVarghese, Please add this comment to your answer, because it have higher vote as than your answer and it helped me too

Comment: @Mani Thanks. I have added the comment to my answer:)